# \odot in gnuplot - mistake

Tags: latex, gnuplot

What is wrong in (R_$\odot$)$ please?

```
set terminal epslatex standalone color
set output 'plot.tex'
set xlabel "$v$ (R$\odot$)" 
set ylabel "$u$ (R$\odot$)" 
plot [-1:1] [-0.6:0.6] 'file.txt' with points pt 7 ps 0.7 lc rgb "navy" notitle
```

It writes odot instead of sing. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful of the difference between strings in single quotes and strings in double quotes.  Because of the double quotes, the backslash at the start of "\odot" is treated as an escape character rather than a literal.  Either use single quotes:

```
set xlabel '$v$ (R$\odot$)' 
set ylabel '$u$ (R$\odot$)'
```

or add an additional escape to preserve the backslash:

```
set xlabel "$v$ (R$\\odot$)" 
set ylabel "$u$ (R$\\odot$)"
```